# при нажатии кнопки у меня выходит ошибка

Tags: swift, button, таймер

вот ошибка

> Thread 1: Exception: "unable to dequeue a cell with identifier carCell
>
> - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard"

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return lappedTimes.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "carCell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = lappedTimes[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var goal: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var trick: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var fail: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var other: UIButton!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    var lappedTimes:[String] = []
    
    private var timer: Timer!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1,
                                     target: self,
                                     selector: #selector(countSeconds(_:)),
                                     userInfo: nil,
                                     repeats: true)
    }
    
    @objc func countSeconds(_ sender: Timer) {
        let date = Date()
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: date)
        let minutes = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)
        let seconds = calendar.component(.second, from: date)
        let hourString = String(hour)
        let minutesString = String(minutes)
        let secondsString = String(seconds)
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.timeLabel.text = hourString + ":" + minutesString + ":" + secondsString
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func goal(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let currentTime = "\(timeLabel.text!)"
        lappedTimes.append(currentTime)

        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    

}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, напишите больше деталей - что вы пытались сделать, какой код вы использовали.

Comment: @IvanKramarchuk у меня есть label в котором показывается настоящее время.Я хочу чтобы по нажатию кнопки текст с label(время) выводилось на label. по принципу работы кнопки "круг" в секундомере. код я приложу в поправке к этому посту

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46069201/9363441

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 0):

Очень малопонятный вопрос, но тем не менее я попытаюсь дать хоть какой-то самодостаточный ответ. Вы добавляете действие при нажатие на кнопку:

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton)
{
   ...
}
```

так же кроме кнопки по логике у вас должен быть виджет списка с вашими данными. Для работы с списком вам нужно добавить такое классы в наследование:

```
class SomeController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
```

дальше в `viewDidLoad()` необходимо подвязать виджет списка к контроллеру:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
}
```

предварительно при этом добавив outlet:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
```

Это все я так понял вы и без меня знаете наверное) Вот ваши методы для поддержки списка:

```
// 1
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

// 2
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return cars.count
}

// 3
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "carCell", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = cars[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

Выше это просто пример. Дальше после того как вы добавляете в массив данные, вам нужно вызвать метод:

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

и список перестроиться уже с новыми данными:

```
@IBAction func goal(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let currentTime = "\(secondLabel.text!)"
    lappedTimes.append(currentTime)

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Вот есть очень [хороший пример](https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/add-rows-table-view-ios-tutorial) который решает вашу проблему. [Туториалы](https://www.ralfebert.de/ios-examples/uikit/uitableviewcontroller/) по работе со списками и [видеоролик](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H9NhYx9xIiU)

### UPDATE

У вас есть массив:

```
var lappedTimes:[String] = []
```

если я правильно понял, то вы в него складываете данные касательно вашего времени из секундомера, значит вы этот массив можете использовать в списке:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return lappedTimes.count
}
```

загрузка данных и отображение:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "carCell", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = lappedTimes[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

Comment: у меня есть секундомер в котором обычное время и оно отображается в label. Мне надо сделать так, чтобы при нажатии кнопки это время выводилось на tableView.

Comment: создайте массив в который будете складывать значения секундомера, и дальше этот массив крепите к списку как в примере и все будет отоборажаться

Comment: и я не очень разбираюсь в коддинге(только начал изучать)

Comment: можете пожалуйста скинуть код. Если вам не сложно

Comment: обновил ответ, посмотрите еще пример, там тоже хорошо рассказано

Comment: можно ли вам как-то написать в лс?

Comment: тут такой функции нету :) что именно вам непонятно

Comment: у вас есть соц сеть в которой мы могли бы связаться?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него

Comment: что мне писать в первом отрывке кода который вы прислали?

Comment: в каком первом отрывке? вам нужно просто при нажатии на кнопку обновить ваш список и все, я приложил видео где решается ваша задача, не могу пока понять где именно у вас возникают сложности и что непонятно

Comment: когда я ввожу этот код '@IBAction func buttonTapped(button: NSButton) {
    }'  мне выходит ошибка Use of undeclared type 'NSButton' что мне делать?

Comment: подправил код, у вас есть метод для обработки нажатий на кнопку, в него нужно просто добавить обновление списка.

Comment: извините если я немного туплю, это просто мой первый опыт работы с кодом

Comment: после добавления классов мне вылезла эта ошибка Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource' как ее исправить?

Comment: Там вам предложат добавить методы, они так же есть в моем ответе

Comment: tableView.reloadData() где этот метод вызывать?

Comment: после добавления данных в массив

Comment: у меня выходит 6 ошибок

Comment: давайте я поправлю этот вопрос(обновлю код) т.к. не уверен что все делаю правильно

Comment: я обновил код, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: можете полный код скинуть или проверить мой?

Comment: ваш код решаете вашу задачу? я не пойму что у вас вызывает сложности?

Comment: после вызова метода у меня выходит 6 ошибок

Comment: вы их решить пытались? я не вижу что у вас происходит)

Comment: когда я запускаю приложение меня сразу перекидывает в Xcode и вылезает ошибка Thread 1: Exception: "[<timerr.ViewController 0x7fa92cc05590> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key fail."

Comment: я не знаю как ее решить

Comment: у вас что-то с таймером который вы запускаете

Comment: тimerr  это название проекта

Comment: Ааа, смотрите тогда на строку из логов я же не вижу что у вас происходит

Comment: я загрузил скриншот, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: я ничем не могу помочь, у вас вылезло исключение которое вы никак не можете исправить, ошибку я там не вижу, ищите способы решения проблемы

Comment: а почему у вас class SomeController? а у меня class ViewController

Comment: у вас какой-то класс наследует класс вьюконтроллера, в моем примере это someclass

Comment: я переписал код, и у меня теперь новая ошибка Thread 1: Exception: "unable to dequeue a cell with identifier carCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard"

Comment: я разобрался с этой ошибкой. спасибо вам большое за то что уделили мне время

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него

Comment: ок, только закончу регистрацию на этом сайте